# How to efficiently pass information from a reducer back to the job?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

In a project, I need to pass numeric information from the reducer(s) of a mapreduce task back to the job. The job basically consists on running a series of mapreduce tasks running on the same data, each one being configured by the result of the previous one. Let's have some example:

I want to determine what the (possibly multi-field) keys are in a set of data. The fields are named A, B, C, and so on. The successive tasks would be:

1. Calculate the cardinality of A.
2. A is not a key. AB might be. Calculate the cardinality of AB.
3. AB is a key. We can deduce that ABC is, too. But we have to calculate the cardinality of B, AC and BC.
4. [...]
5. Write all keys to a file.

Basically, my first idea is to make each cardinality calculation task return a series of counters, one for each candidate, each being assigned exactly once in the reducer. These jobs would have a `NullOutputStream` for output. The problem with that approach is that the numbers of counters are limited, and the number of candidates for each step can possibly be quite huge.

The second idea was to have the reducer output the different counters somewhere on HDFS, and have this passed to the next tasks. Which doesn't work either because the counters are used for the task configuration, but not as its input.

Does anybody have a better idea of how I can make this work?

Comment: so you will go through all possible combinations, like (A,B,C,AB,AC,BC,ABC) if there are 3 fields A,B and C?

Comment: No. The idea of the algorithm is to use previous results to determine new candidates based. For example, if A is a key, AB, AC, and ABC are keys too (but we don't care, since we're looking for minimal keys), no need to test them. If ABC isn't a key, we know for sure we have none in our data. But, for each step, I do need to be able to pass data from the reducer to the job.

Comment: So, you need to iteratively use the same map and reduce code with different input each time (the output of the previous M/R job)? If yes, then maybe this post maight be useful: http://codingwiththomas.blogspot.gr/2011/04/controlling-hadoop-job-recursion.html

Comment: @Pierre What I meant is do you need to check AB, AC and BC or just AB?

Comment: @vefthym: No. For each job, the input is the same (the original data). The output of each mapreduce task is the cardinality for each candidate, which would be used only to configure the next job.

Comment: @HariShankar All these column sets would potentially be tested, at potentially (predictible) different steps. But the exact algorithm really isn't the point here. It is an academic research project, mathematically proven, and it works. The problem is just to pass the result of the reducers back to the job, whatever the algorithm.